# CSS Positioning help ( sprite )

Tags: css, sprite

I have created a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/77dJz/

Somehow ( mind you its 4:30am ) I have cocked up the hover effect on facebook link..

Twitter one works... just not sure what I have done wrong.

Any help appreciated, I am tired lol.

To Iterate:

CSS:

```
#facebook {
    background:url('../images/socialsprite.png') no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
    height:40px;
    width:180px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:30px;
}
#facebook:hover {
    background:url('../images/socialsprite.png') no-repeat scroll 0px -40px transparent;
    height:40px;
    width:180px;
}
#twitter {
    background:url('../images/socialsprite.png') no-repeat scroll -180px 0px transparent;
    height:40px;
    width:180px;
    margin-left:210px;
    margin-top:-40px;
}
#twitter:hover {
    background:url('../images/socialsprite.png') no-repeat scroll -180px -40px transparent;
    height:40px;
    width:180px;
}
```

Cheers

Need twitter and facebook sprite to sit side by side horizontally centered in the master div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is `float` your `divs` so they don't cover each other.

Here is some simplified CSS.  Edit the `margin`s as needed.

```
#facebook {
background:url('http://sitehelp.com.au/images/socialsprite.png') 
no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
height:40px;
width:180px;
float:left;
margin:25px 10px;     
}
#facebook:hover {
background:url('http://sitehelp.com.au/images/socialsprite.png') 
no-repeat scroll 0px -40px transparent;
}
#twitter {
background:url('http://sitehelp.com.au/images/socialsprite.png') 
no-repeat scroll -180px 0px transparent;
height:40px;
width:180px;
float:right;
margin:25px 10px;    
}
#twitter:hover {
background:url('http://sitehelp.com.au/images/socialsprite.png') 
no-repeat scroll -180px -40px transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/77dJz/3/

**EDIT**

You could further simplify your CSS as follows:

```
#facebook, #twitter {
background:url('http://sitehelp.com.au/images/socialsprite.png') no-repeat scroll transparent;
height:40px;
width:180px;
float:left;
margin:25px 10px;     
}
#facebook:hover {
background-position:0px -40px;
}

#twitter {
background-position:-180px 0px;
float:right;
}
#twitter:hover {
background-position: -180px -40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/77dJz/4/

Comment: No probs.  Happy to help.  See above edit for further simplification of your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

**Quote:**  *"...just not sure what I have done wrong."*

The problem is that your Twitter `<div>` is covering your Facebook `<div>`.

<s>Simply deleting the Twitter `<div>` gets your Facebook `<div>` working again...</s>

And if you want side by side `<div>`, you need to float them.

this is working...

http://jsfiddle.net/77dJz/2/

Comment: yeah lol, I am tired.. will check out your fiddle. Hmm the twitter one doesnt display

Comment: @422:  Although I did not provide a working solution immediately, I found the reason for your failure and answered your precise question first.  Without floating the divs, one covered the other preventing your hover.